# Storing remainder values

Tags: c#

I'm trying to store values of my remainder in a string variable collect. I am not sure how to keep adding characters to the string as the program iterates through the loop. I have not learnt how to use arrays yet so I am trying to store it as a string type. How do I add characters to a string from a loop without overwriting the previous characters?

```
int quotient = integer / 2;
int remainder = integer % 2;
int temp = remainder;

Console.WriteLine(remainder);

while( quotient >= 2);
{
    integer = quotient;
    quotient = integer / 2;
    remainder = integer % 2;

    string collect = string.Format("{0}{1}",temp,remainder);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to store the remainder in a string?

Comment: You want to use `StringBuilder.Append`

Comment: well it doesnt have to be in a string but I dont see any other basic type to save it in. I have not learnt StringBuilder either so I want to somehow do this with basic types (i.e int,double,string,char etc...)

Comment: "I want to somehow do this with basic types..." What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Without considering the reason **why** you want to do it, I tried providing you two ways to do it in the answer one with a StringBuilder (good practice) and one with just Strings (bad practice).

Comment: I am working on a project that basically asks user for an integer input and spits out the binary encoding of that number.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel then. `int i = 50; string s = Convert.ToString(i, 2);`

Comment: @rshepp considering he's just learning how to write C# programs I suppose that his project is more about writing the algorithm than calling an already implemented framework feature.

Comment: Also, pay attention to your temp variable.   If integer = 51, temp will always be 1 from line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skipping over **why** you want to do it, if you have to do several string manipulations, the best way to do it would be to use a `StringBuilder`, doing something like

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
while( condition ){
   //Stuffs
   sb.Append("StuffsYouWantToAppend");
}
string output=sb.ToString();
```

A simpler way would be to just do:

```
String collect=String.Empty;
while ( condition )
   //Stuffs
   collect+="StuffsYouWantToAppend";
}
```

It would not be advisable to do so, because it's a bad practice since strings are immutable and you're not changing it, but just creating a new one.

Comment: writing collect+="something" is the same as writing collect=collect+"something", which means: create a new string, that starts with the old string and follows with the new provided string.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use a StringBuilder instead.

```
String result;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(your_length);   

 while( quotient >= 2);
 {
        integer = quotient;
        quotient = integer / 2;
        remainder = integer % 2;

        sb.Append(temp+ " " + remainder);
 }

result = sb.ToString();
```